# Get (Planner) Plan details using Graph API and Flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

As a first step I am trying to get the details of a plan in my Planner. I have followed the instructions in the post nelow but I am still a bit stuck.

http://blogopaxio.azurewebsites.net/accessing-graph-api-from-microsoft-flow-using-application-permissions-2/

That seems to work, I can retrieve all my groups and even create a  new group. So for example https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$orderby=displayName works just fine. My problems start when I am trying to get the details of a plan,

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/planner/plans/{plan-id} works in Graph Explorer but fails in my flow with "Unauthorized" as the error. I am aware I can use the existing flow connector for this but my final objective is to create checklist items which are not yet supported. My understanding is that I need a second token somehow, is that doable with flow?

Comment: According to this post https://lazyadmin.nl/it/using-microsoft-graph-api-with-powershell/, I will have to pass an authcode apart from access token, I guess the question is that doable without a login prompt in flow or an azure function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Planner APIs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannerplan_get) do not support Application permissions, only Delegated. Since Flow runs headless, it isn't possible to work with Planner from Flow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc, I am still trying to get my head around this, do you think It will be possible to workaround the limitation using an Azure function and the code from the post above provided that you end up with the auth code in a text file, how long is that valid for?

Comment: Tokens typically only live for an hour. Flow isn't a really good fit for this kind of scenario. Even if you could get around the token issue, you still have the problem of determining which token (i.e. which user) you want to be operating as during any given execution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc

Comment: Great answer. Any idea why this limitation is in place? Also, I'm wondering if there isn't a way to bounce a request outside of Flow and achieve this with the help of another machine.

Comment: This isn't a flow problem, it's an authentication problem. You need to authenticate a specific user in order to call the API. You can do this with Flow but it means you need a separate Flow for each user you're authenticating. In other words, you can easily call into your _own_ plans, but not someone else's.